# programatically set custom data to select2

Tags: jquery-select2-4

How can I set custom data to a select2 v.4 per javascript?  I understand that you can set the id and text value by inserting an option tag but that does not cover all the other data I want to have there in addition, e.g. `[{"id":"17","text":"22.09.2015 15:45:05","branchList":["20","1","3","4","5"]}]`

I use this code to set up the control, which works perfect:

```js
$('#image_id').select2({
  placeholder: "Search image ...",
  minimumInputLength: 0,
  allowClear: true,
  dropdownAutoWidth: true,
  theme: "bootstrap",
  ajax: {
    url: "ajax/select2_image_search.php",
    delay: 250,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: function (params) {
      return {
        keywords: params.term
      };
    },
    processResults: function (data, page) {
      return {
        results: data
      };
    }
  },
});
```

when I then use this code, I can extract not only id and text but also custom data like `branchList`:

```js
var bList = $('#image_id').select2("data")[0]["branchList"];
```

this works well too, but how can I set the additional info programatically per script with e.g. this data `[{"id":"18","text":"23.09.2015 15:45:05","branchList":["22","5","7","32","1"]}]` so that I can retrieve the additional info lateron per javascript?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is put your custom data to id with JSON.stringify(). Maybe it is not good way but it works for me.

So your code transforms to:

```
[ {
    "id" : JSON.stringify({
        "id" : "18",
        "branchList" : [ "22", "5", "7", "32", "1" ]
    }),
    "text" : "23.09.2015 15:45:05"
} ]
```

And you can later extract your data back by `JSON.parse(selector.selectedOptions[0].value)`.